# Filter array on date with php

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, date, filter

I need some help with filtering an array on date.

The query below will print a table with all entry's ever. But i wan't to filter on date.
If for example today is '30-12-2014' i want to show all entry's from 30-12-2014 and "newer" and not from the first entry thats older then '30-12-2014'.

The "appointment.start_time" is a varchar2 with an output like: 2014-11-28T15:35:00

In the $stid i trim the "appointment.start_time" with substr so the output is like "2014-11-28".

But how do i put the filter in?

Something like this?

```
foreach ($row as $item)
    if ($item->dateitem >= $startDate  &&  
        $item->dateitem <= $endDate)
            $newarray[] = $item;
```

Can you help me please?

Kind regards,
Ritchie

--------------------------------------------------- query php ----------------------------------------------------------

```html
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select 
customer.first_name as VOORNAAM, 
customer.last_name as ACHTERNAAM, 
substr(appointment.start_time,1,10) as DATUM,  
substr(appointment.start_time,12,10) as STARTTIJD, 
service_definitions.external_name as PRODUCT, 
appointment.resource_name as AGENDA 
from appointment 
inner join appointment_customer on appointment.id = appointment_customer.appointmentjpa_id inner join customer on customer.id = appointment_customer.customerids 
inner join appointment_service on appointment_service.appointment_id = appointment.id inner join service_definitions on service_definitions.id = appointment_service.service_id  order by appointment.start_time asc ");


    oci_execute($stid);

        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            echo " < tr > \n ";
            foreach ($row as $item)
           {
            echo "< td >" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "< /td >\n";
            }
            echo "< /tr >\n";
```

------------------------------ SOLVED WITH QUERY ----------------------------------

Hi there all, I solved my problem  by adding the following in the query:

```
where substr(appointment.start_time,1,10) >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

@krishna put me on the right track. I know that there are more and better ways to handle this but for me its working fine with this.

Thanks all for the help.
Regards
Ritchie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query like this

```
SELECT
customer.first_name as VOORNAAM, 
customer.last_name as ACHTERNAAM, 
substr(appointment.start_time,1,10) as DATUM,  
substr(appointment.start_time,12,10) as STARTTIJD, 
service_definitions.external_name as PRODUCT
, appointment.resource_name as AGENDA
from appointment  where 
CONCAT(Year( STR_TO_DATE( appointment.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) ),'-',Month( STR_TO_DATE( appointment.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) ),'-',Day( STR_TO_DATE( appointment.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) )) > '2014-12-30' order by appointment.start_time asc
```

Comment: Note: Please try to avoid storing dates as strings

Comment: @RitchieTomasouw did you changed any thing from this query

Comment: can you post the new query to debug

Comment: @RitchieTomasouw you should post this as question, this is surely having some structural error which i cant resolve it, may be others can help you if you post it as question

Comment: @RitchieTomasouw i am really sorry, i didn't notice the tag. I dont have idea about Oracle DB

Comment: this is the working where statement in oracle:  where substr(appointment.start_time,1,10) >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use strtotime() function to first convert the date to unixtimestamp and then to compare them.

Like below:

```
$row = array('30-12-2014','29-12-2014','28-12-2014','27-12-2014','26-12-2014','25-12-2014');
$startDate = '26-12-2014';
$endDate = '28-12-2014';
foreach ($row as $item)
    if ( strtotime($item) >= strtotime($startDate)  &&  strtotime($item) <= strtotime($endDate))
            $newarray[] = $item;

print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter function. I don't know how exactly your data looks, but you might be able to figure out how to do it based on the following example:

```
$arr = [strtotime('now'), strtotime('now-1'), strtotime('now+1')]
array_filter($arr, function($elem) { return $elem > 1419935201; })
```

where 1419935201 is a value of strtotime('now');

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment.  Where do i put this code? in the foreach ?

Comment: Replece the fragment 
'foreach ($row as $item)
       {
        echo "< td >" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "< /td >\n";'

with

$filtered = array_filter($row, function($date) use ($startDate, $endDate) { return strtotime($item) >= strtotime($startDate)  &&  strtotime($item) <= strtotime($endDate) });

and the iterate over $filtered array